docker jumpserver cannot connect docker redis
I want to deploy jumpserver on a single server, and I am currently using mysql:8.0, redis:7.4.1, jumpserver/all:v4.3.0.
The command I use is:
# Start the MySQL container
docker run -d -p 3306:3306 --name mysql-jms --hostname mysql-jms -v /home/test/docker_datas/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql -v  /home/test/docker_datas/mysql/logs:/var/log/mysql -v /home/test/docker_datas/mysql/conf:/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d -e  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=jumpserver -e MYSQL_USER=jumpserver -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=jumpserver  mysql:8.0 --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_bin. --restart=always --privileged=true

# Start the Redis container, map local port 6380, set the container to restart automatically, configure the system parameters and set the access password
docker run -d -it --name redis-jms --hostname redis-jumpserver -p 6380:6379 -v /opt/redis/data:/data --restart=always  --privileged=true --sysctl net.core.somaxconn=1024 redis:7.4.1 --requirepass "123456"

# Start the Jumpserver container, set the host name to jumpserver, and configure the container to restart automatically
docker run -d --name jumpserver -h jumpserver --restart=always -v /data/jumpserver:/opt/jumpserver/data/media -p 81:80  -p 2222:2222 -e SECRET_KEY=$SECRET_KEY -e BOOTSTRAP_TOKEN=$BOOTSTRAP_TOKEN -e DB_HOST=10.0.4.4 -e DB_PORT= 3306-e DB_USER=root -e DB_ENGINE=mysql -e DB_PASSWORD="123456" -e DB_NAME=jumpserver -e REDIS_HOST=10.0.4.4 -e REDIS_PORT=6380 -e REDIS_PASSWORD="123456" jumpserver/jms_all:v4.3.0

But now it shows:
mv: cannot remove 'opt/jumpserver/data/media':Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove 'opt/jumpserver/data/media':Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove 'var/log/nginx':Device or resource busy
>> Init database
External database skip start, 192.168.30.252
>> Init nginx
External redis server skip start, 192.168.30.252
Starting periodic command scheduler: cron.
Error:dial tcp 192.168.30.252:6380: connect: connection timed out
wait for redis 192.168.30.252 ready

I have tried:
nc -zv 192.168.30.252 6380

res = Connection to 192.168.30.252 6380 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
telnet 192.168.30.252 6380

res =
Trying 192.168.30.252...
Connected to 192.168.30.252.
Escape character is '^]'.
docker exec -it redis-jms redis-cli -a 123456 ping

res = PONG
I want to end up on a PC, open the server's public IP address :81, and log into the admin account.

I kindly request that you format the code.

sorry, I format my code just now.
I was able to do this successfully in VMware on my personal computer. My VM version is Ubuntu 20.04.6 Desktop and my server is Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.
